# Javascript: hide and show text using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new in javascript. What I am trying to do is hide and show some text on click using vanilla javascript. I don't know what am I doing wrong here is the code:

this is HTML code:

```
<p class="h5 font-weight-normal">some text<span id="toggle-content" class="toggle- 
content" aria-hidden="true">some other text</span></p>
<a class="text-danger toggle-button" aria-controls="toggle-content">show more</a>
```

this is javascript code:

```
const a = document.querySelector('.toggle-button');

if(a){
a.addEventListener('click', () => {
const content = document.querySelector('.toggle-content');
const ariaHidden = content.getAttribute('aria-hidden');

content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', ariaHidden === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true');

const atext = content.getAttribute('aria-hidden') === 'true' ? 'Show' : 'Hide';

a.innerHTML = `${atext} more`;
});
}
```

this is css code:

```
.toggle-content {
display: none;
}

.toggle-content[aria-hidden="false"] {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: it is working perfectly what do you want to do to it ?

Comment: it is not working properly for me. Somehow it is not changing the area-hidden attribute of span to true or false. It is just changing the text of a tag to show more and hide more

Answer (score 0):

you had added line break in `<p class="h5 font-weight-normal">some text<span id="toggle-content" class="toggle- <!-- here you have added a line break which should not be inside an attribute -->
content" aria-hidden="true">some other text</span></p>`

```js
const a = document.querySelector('.toggle-button');

if(a){
a.addEventListener('click', () => {
const content = document.querySelector('.toggle-content');
const ariaHidden = content.getAttribute('aria-hidden');

content.setAttribute('aria-hidden', ariaHidden === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true');

const atext = content.getAttribute('aria-hidden') === 'true' ? 'Show' : 'Hide';

a.innerHTML = `${atext} more`;
});
}
```

```css
.toggle-content {
display: none;
}

.toggle-content[aria-hidden="false"] {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class="h5 font-weight-normal">some text<span id="toggle-content" class="toggle-content" aria-hidden="true">some other text</span></p>
<a class="text-danger toggle-button" aria-controls="toggle-content">show more</a>
```

Comment: it is StackOverflow not me! I don't have line break in my actual code

Comment: yes if the `span` inside  `p` tag is changing the aria-hidden attribute.. what more you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your first p tag, write this tag correct. I try to simplify your approach, try to add/remove active class for your element, for example:

```
const a = document.querySelector('.toggle-button');
const content = document.querySelector('.toggle-content');

a.addEventListener('click', () => {
content.classList.includes('active') ? content.classList.remove('active') : content.classList.add('active');
});

.toggle-content {
display: none
}

.active {
display: block
}
```

Why you use if(a), maybe because your element not yet appeared, to avoid cases like this, try to wrap your code in `document.onload` it will be called when the document is ready.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you made mistake. Change this:

```
const content = document.querySelector('.toggle-content');
```

to:

```
const content = document.querySelector('#toggle-content');
```

or even better

```
const content = document.getElementById('toggle-content');
```